# How to get specific data from sqlite3 by assigning variable

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to get the data whose name is John by passing it to a function, but it confuses me on how to use the variable since it's inside a string.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db)
c = conn.cursor()

def getName(name):
    data = c.execute("""SELECT * FROM data WHERE Name={name} """).fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    print(data)
    conn.close

getName('John')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

```py
data = c.execute('SELECT * FROM data WHERE Name=(?)', (name,)).fetchall()
```

Comment: I am afraid I understood your point correctly 

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a quote in line 1: `conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db)` and you have to call `conn.close()` like this. You can use f-strings for the execution line.